# How to add another condition in this function

Tags: swift

How can i add another condition to my function, for another textfield and how to make this code is more simple

```
   func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if let text = textField.text {
            if let floatingLabelTextField = textField as? SkyFloatingLabelTextField {
                if(text.characters.count < 3 || !text.containsString("@")) {
                    floatingLabelTextField.errorMessage = "Invalid email"
                }
                else {
                    // The error message will only disappear when we reset it to nil or empty string
                    floatingLabelTextField.errorMessage = ""
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Create a function and pass your textfield reference as parameter in that function. Create your conditional logic in that function.

Comment: assign tag to textfield textfield1.tag = 1, textfield2.tag = 2 and inside shouldChangeCharactersInRange func check which textfield edit like if textField.tag == 1 {  // code for textfiled1  }else { // code for textfield2 }

Comment: Is this an Email Validation ?

Answer (score 1):

Below code will be more simpler and easy to add any new condition:

```
func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"

    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
    return emailTest.evaluate(with: testStr)
}

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let text = textField.text else{
        return true
    }

    guard let floatingLabelTextField = textField as? SkyFloatingLabelTextField else {
        return true
    }

    if isValidEmail(testStr: text)  {
        floatingLabelTextField.errorMessage = ""
    }else{
        floatingLabelTextField.errorMessage = "Invalid email"
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Your email regex is terribly outdated nowadays :-( IDN and IPv6 are a thing now.

Answer (score 0):

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool

{
    if textField == textField as? SkyFloatingLabelTextField && (!textField.text.containsString("@") || textField.text.characters.count    < 3 )
    {
            floatingLabelTextField.errorMessage = "Invalid email"
    }
    else
    {
        floatingLabelTextField.errorMessage = ""
    }

return true
}
```

You can check firstly if textfield is your selected textfield and in same condition you can also check email validation.

Comment: You can't compare a `UITextField` with `String`.